# Old google analytics ID's will work on new Universal Analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I can't find any info about that on google.

What wil happen with all my old apps that uses old analytics ID's (for example `UA-41984212-1`).

Will continue working perfectly when i update the source code of my apps migrating the java functions and code to the new universal analytics java functions and code from the new library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it possible not to upgrade your id, but you won't have access to all new features:

> Although updating your tracking code (Step 2) is optional at this
>   time, you won't have access to the all of the benefits until you
>   update your tracking code to a Universal Analytics tracking code, like
>   the analytics.js library or Mobile SDK v2.x or higher for Android and
>   iOS. Legacy libraries, like ga.js or v1.x of the Mobile SDKs, will be
>   supported until Phase 4 of Universal Analytics Upgrade, at which time
>   they will be deprecated.

More details:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/guide#overview

Comment: so... the old id's will work with the new source code?

Comment: I haven't used universal analytics with my apps yet (I still use old version), but explanation makes me believe, that it will work like a charm